# Can not connect to remote pc with powershell

Tags: powershell, server, remote-access

I connect from one computer to another remote computer with powershell.

For this to work I did some configuration on both computer according to this video:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itmanagement/ff765030.aspx

But still I get an error message when I try to do this on the local computer:

```
enter-pssession -comp remotePC -credential domain\username
```

Then I enter the password and hit enter.

I get this error:

Connecting to remote server LocalPC failed with the following error message :

```
 The WS-Management service cannot process the request. The 
service is configured to not accept any remote shell requests. For more 
CategoryInfo : OpenError: (LocalPC:String) [], PSRemotingTrans
portException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoteSessionDisallowed,PSSessionStateBroken
```

The "Windows Remote Management"-Service is started on the remote PC.

I totally disabled the firewall for test purpose totally on the remote PC.

I did also `enable-psremoting` and `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts` *

When I execute on the remote PC:

`winrm config` it says:

```
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

What else of that 1000 things do I still have to enable that I can connect to my remote pc with powershell?

**UPDATE**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm get winrm/config/service

Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = false
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = false
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = *
    IPv6Filter = *
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true


PS C:\Windows\system32> winrm e winrm/config/listener

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = xx.xx.xx.xx, 127.0.0.1, ::1, fe80::4c2c:a8d0:6046:764d%11
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> dir WSMan:\localhost\Shell\


   WSManConfig: Microsoft.WSMan.Management\WSMan::localhost\Shell

Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   AllowRemoteShellAccess         GPO             false
System.String   IdleTimeout                                    7200000
System.String   MaxConcurrentUsers                             10
System.String   MaxShellRunTime                                2147483647
System.String   MaxProcessesPerShell                           25
System.String   MaxMemoryPerShellMB                            1024
System.String   MaxShellsPerUser                               30
```

Comment: How about ``dir WSMan:\localhost\Shell\``?

Comment: See UPDATE 2 for my answer @PetSerAl

Comment: As you can see: `System.String AllowRemoteShellAccess GPO false` — your group policy does not allow remote shell access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from `dir WSMan:\localhost\Shell\` output:

```
Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   AllowRemoteShellAccess         GPO             false
```

WS-Management configuration property `AllowRemoteShellAccess` have value `false` with source `GPO`. That means: group policy applied to target computer does disallow remote shell access.